# global variable from jquery .load() page not recognized by remote javascript file function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**EDIT**

To make it easier to read I've rewritten my explanation here.

In short, a function in remote .js file requires a global variable. A previous function in remote .js file brings that var into the page with the jQuery .load(), but the function that requires the variable is not finding it after the .load() has brought it into the page. Below functions are in chronological order.

The remote .js file is loaded into the main page before the .load() page is.

Below is the code that I have:

**Function Loads Remote Page Into Main Page (in remote .js file)**

```
$(".activity_choice").live('click',function(e) {
    var selection = $(this).attr('id');
    var address = my_url + "pg/course/activity_form?style=" + selection + "&activity=" + activity;
    $("#stage_choice_holder").load(address,function(){
    });
});
```

**The Global Var Coming In With Loaded Page**

```
var controls_setup = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($setup);?>');
```

**The Final Function That Should Save Things Using This Variable (in remote .js file)**

```
$("#save_controls").live('click',function(e) {
    datastr = "&activity=" + activity;
    $.each(controls_setup, function (i,elem) {
        datastr += "&"+elem+"=" + $("#"+elem).attr('value');
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url + "action/course/saveactivitycontrols",
        data: datastr,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
        }
    }); 
});
```

The global variable `controls_setup` is not being recognized (I think), because when the `$(".activity_choice").live('click',function(e) {` is clicked the main page is already rendered with the remote .js file in it. This function brings the global variable in, but I'm guessing the DOM isn't picking it up. So the final function that requires this var can't find it.

Hope this is clearer.
Any help much appreciated. I am a somewhat novice with jQuery.

Comment: MUCH easier to understand, thank you. I think I worked it out (I was editing while you were editing), see updated answer.

Comment: edited the issue above to make it clearer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It's very hard to tell exactly what's going on in that code, because there's lots of code quoted which is unrelated to the problem, and (conversely) it's quoted in somewhat disconnected bits.</s> *(You've fixed that, nice one.)*

But if I understand you correctly, this call from your first code block:

```
$("#stage_choice_holder").load(...);
```

...is loading HTML with embedded `script` elements from a PHP page, and in a `script` element on that page you have:

```
var controls_setup = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($setup);?>');
```

First off, you don't want that `parseJSON` call, simply this:

```
var controls_setup = <?php echo json_encode($setup);?>;
```

`json_encode` will return valid JSON, which conveniently (and intentionally) is a subset of JavaScript object literal notation, so the end result there is that `controls_setup` will receive a reference to an object. This may actually be the problem, because throwing single quotes around the output of `json_encode` may well result in a syntax error (if there are any single quotes in the material output by `json_encode`, or line breaks).

Then in code later, you're trying to access `controls_setup` and not seeing it.

Although not best practice, that should work because of the way jQuery ensures things get loaded. Here's a very simple example of it ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/afihiz)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  display("Before: " + typeof foo);
  $("#target").load("http://jsbin.com/uwigok", function() {
    display("After: " + typeof foo);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

...which loads

```
<div>Snippet</div>
<script>
  var foo = "bar";
</script>
```

So it could be as simple as removing the `parseJSON` call per the above.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have had issues with the parseJSON, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I've tried your recommendation and I'm still getting a "controls_setup is not defined". I still think it's because perhaps I'm not defining it properly as a global var, or that because the function thath uses it is already rendered before the global var comes into the page, the function can't find it

Comment: if I put the function that uses the variable into the page that comes in with .load() the function can find the variable. It seems to be because it's in the remote .js file that it has difficulty finding the incoming var.

Comment: @Trajan: No, all scripts end up sharing the same global space, it doesn't matter whether they're external or embedded in the page. That makes literally **no** difference. If you're seeing a difference when you do that, it means you're changing something else at the same time (like the location of the scripts relative to each other).

Comment: ok, I'll keep plugging away at it and see if I can come up with some more information.

Comment: @Trajan: Here's an updated version of my example using an external script: http://jsbin.com/afihiz/2 What you'll need to do is walk through the code with a debugger so you can see what's going on. All major browsers now have debuggers built in. I quite like Chrome's Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I will show them), but again, all the major browsers have them now.

Comment: I've been testing with alerts for controls_setup at certain points throughout the chronology of using the page. No alert appears unless I declare the global variable in the remote .js file before everything else. If I don't declare it there, and only in the incoming file the alert doesn't show. So perhaps what I need to do is declare it in the remote .js file first and then **update** it when I load the incoming page? **EDIT** I use Chrome's debugger all the time to find bugs from it's Console tabs, the rest of it I'm a little daunted by

Comment: @Trajan: `alert` debugging went out years ago. :-) Definitely worth using a proper debugger. You can see what's going on dramatically more clearly, inspect any variable you want, etc., etc.

Comment: not actually sure what I did (tried a lot of things then off for dinner, came back and it worked). The last thing was to change the var controls_setup to remove the parseJSON. Thanks for your help on this.